# Is there a ActionNameAttribute in ASP.NET MVC 3 for class type declarations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Can't imagine this question hasn't been asked yet... although, I can't find it.

So here it goes: I've used the ActionNameAttribute a lot on my action methods in ASP.NET MVC 3. Like this:

```
[ActionName("confirm")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Confirm(string stuffTitle)
{
   ActionResult resultView = CreateSomeStuff(stuffTitle);
   return resultView;
}
```

But, how can I accomplish the same for classes? Like this:

```
[ActionName("personal")]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

With the [ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) it's only possible on method declartions. But I guess it should somehow be possible on class type declarations. Maybe another attribute I haven't heard of yet? Some other workaround?

Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ActionName on a controller? In what purpose? This hasn't been asked before as the goal looks pretty strange and hardly makes any sense. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Why don't you just change the name of your controller?

Comment: I found this post looking for a way to give an Alias to a controller, which is precisely what I think @Monty is after. My reason is a conflict between naming conventions and the desired URL.

Comment: @Dead.Rabit Yep, that's the same problem. Didn't find a better solution than the answer given below... if you do, please share, thanks!

Comment: @Monty, I'm afraid I don't have a solution, I wanted to have 2 controllers with the same Alias (SOC) so in the end I kept both controllers and added Redirects from the correctly named one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really have hard time understanding what are you after. You want to change the name of your controller or something? If so use a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "FooRoute",
    "foo/{action}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now all requests to `foo/someaction` will be routed to the corresponding action of the `Account` controller.

Comment: Best answer given in my opinion. Just like the {action} and {id} alias in the route path, I guess it would be logical to also add more control to the {controller} alias in the route path. Unfortunately not possible in the way I expected. Creating a seperate route does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MVC Controllers contain methods which can map to Actions. So as Darin says, what purpose would it achieve on a class? To say this class has a 'list' action, wouldn't help. You'd have to say which method as well, wouldn't you?

I found this article on Phil Haack's blog, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx  . I apologise in advance if you've already read it. I think what he says and some of the resulting discussion might help you.

Comment: Maybe little clarification: since I use the ActionNameAttribute for aliasing a method (lowercasing f.i., i17n), I just thought the same should possible with class declarations.

Comment: I kind of see what you're getting at. As an analogy, the controller is a box; an attribute at the top would tell me what's in it. However, with actions you're more interested in the method itself, not the container that holds it.